# Validate date using jquery masked input plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, gwt

I am using jquery masked input plugin for masking of input fields. I am using `GWT` and using jquery mask input function using `JSNI`.

For date field having mask like "`MM/dd/yyyy`",

how can I restrict user not to enter `month >12 or day >31`...

My implementation is as follows:

```
 $wnd.$.mask.definitions['y'] = '[12]';
    $wnd.$.mask.definitions['m'] = '[01]';
    $wnd.$.mask.definitions['d'] = '[0-3]';

    if (pattern== 'MM/DD/YYYY') {
        $wnd.$(id).mask("m9/d9/y999", {
            placeholder : p
    });
```

Here in month field, there are `2 digits(MM)`,

- first digit can be restricted to 0 to 1
- second digit not able to control

I tried with conditional regex, not working fine.

Anything with conditional regex is also fine.

Basically I want user to enter only valid dates.

Please suggest.

Thanks.